# Execute INSERT in case no conditional statement occurs

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I have a PHP file that checks if any of the 3 possible words given trough $_POST have already been created on DB.

If any of those words do exist on any of DB records, it echoes an error.

If none of those words exist on any DB records, it executes an INSERT query.

This code checks correctly wheter any of the 3 given words (if given) exists, and if it does, the error is echoed properly. But if none of those exists, the website just freezes and no insert is made.

How could I ask PHP to run the INSERT query (what is now placed on the ELSE statement) in case all IF statements are false?

```
    $ca_key1 = $_POST['ca_key1'];
    $ca_key2 = $_POST['ca_key2'];
    $ca_key3 = $_POST['ca_key3'];

    if ($ca_key1!=="" || $ca_key2!=="" || $ca_key3!==""){

        $selectKeys = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3 FROM ws_campaigns WHERE ca_fk_us_id='$id'");

        if ($ca_key1!==""){            
            while($registroKeys = mysqli_fetch_array($selectKeys)){
               if ($registroKeys['ca_key1']===$ca_key1 || $registroKeys['ca_key2']===$ca_key1 || $registroKeys['ca_key3']===$ca_key1){
                   echo "No se ha creado la campaña. La palabra ".$ca_key1." ya está siendo utilizada en una campaña previa.";
               } 
            }      
        }

        else if ($ca_key2!==""){
            while($registroKeys = mysqli_fetch_array($selectKeys)){
               if ($registroKeys['ca_key1']===$ca_key2 || $registroKeys['ca_key2']===$ca_key2 || $registroKeys['ca_key3']===$ca_key2){
                   echo "No se ha creado la campaña. La palabra '".$ca_key2."' ya está siendo utilizada en una campaña previa.";
               } 
            }      
        } 

        else if ($ca_key3!==""){
            while($registroKeys = mysqli_fetch_array($selectKeys)){
               if ($registroKeys['ca_key1']===$ca_key3 || $registroKeys['ca_key2']===$ca_key3 || $registroKeys['ca_key3']===$ca_key3){
                   echo "No se ha creado la campaña. La palabra '".$ca_key3."' ya está siendo utilizada en una campaña previa.";
               } 
            }      
        } 

        else{
            //DEVOLUCIÓN ID CAMPAÑA
            if ($result = $con->query("INSERT INTO ws_campaigns (ca_id, ca_name, ca_content, ca_fk_us_id, ca_img, ca_prefix,ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3) VALUES ('','$ca_title', '$ca_content','$id','$ca_img','$ca_prefix','$ca_key1','$ca_key2','$ca_key3')")) {
                 echo $con->insert_id;
              }
        }


    }

    else{
        //DEVOLUCIÓN ID CAMPAÑA
        if ($result = $con->query("INSERT INTO ws_campaigns (ca_id, ca_name, ca_content, ca_fk_us_id, ca_img, ca_prefix,ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3) VALUES ('','$ca_title', '$ca_content','$id','$ca_img','$ca_prefix','$ca_key1','$ca_key2','$ca_key3')")) {
           echo $con->insert_id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Got it. Thank you Marc, I'll fix that after.

Comment: so, why not use all variables in the `where` clause using `AND`? if that's what the question is about.

Comment: It sound to me like your $con->query() is returning false, and you're not outputting anything.  Is that right?  Did you try adding some extra debugging like mysql_error() to check?

Comment: *"But if none of those exists, the website just freezes and no insert is made."* - Check for errors  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php as to exactly why it's failing.

Comment: here, you've an answer now http://stackoverflow.com/a/30443636/ yeah,... ok. well, my comment isn't going anywhere then. question seems to have gone stale now.

Comment: I have just tried to get the error, but no error displays. It is just (I think) that, when any of those statements is true, the loop just gets inside of thta statement and checks the word's existance. In case it exists, it echoes the error and stops there (works OK), but in case it does not exist, it does not continue with the loop: it also stops there and does not keep on checking the other statements, and in case all of them are FALSE, making the last ELSE statement containing the INSERT.

Comment: I have tried the case when ca_key1 / 2 / 3 have no value: it makes the correct INSERT on database (works OK). I have tried the case that ca_key1 is sent, but it already exists on database: error emerges (works OK). But if I send a value in ca_key1 / 2 / 3, and that value DOES NOT EXIST on database, the loop does not continue till the INSERT, it stops on the statement where value is checked -- example: ($ca_key1!==""){STOPS HERE}

Comment: The problem is when ca_key1 or ka_key2 or ca_key3 is NOT EMPTY and value DOES NOT EXIST on database...

Comment: `WHERE ca_fk_us_id='$id' AND '$ca_key1' ='???'  AND '$ca_key2' ='???'  AND '$ca_key2' ='???' ");` or replace `AND` by `OR` then handle on the errors after.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I am almost sure there's the issue. But I do have problems on making big queries, and I guess I am placing wrongly the AND / OR  expressions, as the updated code you can see on the top of the question always echoes "MATCHES FOUND", even when there are not matches. Could you advice me how to order the query? Just check edited question. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. It always MATCHES because there are empty ca_key1 / 2 / 3 values on database. Keep trying :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have another `else if` as check

```
else if(empty($ca_key3) && empty($ca_key2) && empty($ca_key1))
{

}
```

Be explicit to ensure that

Comment: I have tried the case when ca_key1 / 2 / 3 have no value: it makes the correct INSERT on database (works OK). I have tried the case that ca_key1 is sent, but it already exists on database: error emerges (works OK). But if I send a value in ca_key1 / 2 / 3, and that value DOES NOT EXIST on database, the loop does not continue till the INSERT, it stops on the statement where value is checked -- example: ($ca_key1!==""){STOPS HERE}

Comment: The problem is when ca_key1 or ka_key2 or ca_key3 is NOT EMPTY and value DOES NOT EXIST on database...

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens to your result when executing the query:

```
$result = mysqli_query(...);
if (!$result) {
    die('error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

It's probably failing and the error info will tell you why.

Comment: OP isn't using `mysql_`. Plus this is a comment if anything which you have enough rep for.

Comment: uh...mysqli_query, mysqli_fetch_array; I mean, it's mysqli instead of mysql, but...

Comment: And I believe this is the correct answer to the question

Comment: sure if you say so. OP should accept it then. Give them a shout ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was, as mented by [Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) that the way of solving this was creting a single INSERT query, combining AND, OR in order to make a single check on the database.

This way has solved correctly the issue:

```
if ($ca_key1!=="" || $ca_key2!=="" || $ca_key3!==""){

        $selectKeys = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3 FROM ws_campaigns WHERE ca_fk_us_id='$id' AND ("
                . "   (ca_key1!='' AND ca_key1='$ca_key1') OR (ca_key2!='' AND ca_key2='$ca_key1') OR (ca_key3!='' AND ca_key3='$ca_key1') "
                . "OR (ca_key1!='' AND ca_key1='$ca_key2') OR (ca_key2!='' AND ca_key2='$ca_key2') OR (ca_key3!='' AND ca_key3='$ca_key2')"
                . "OR (ca_key1!='' AND ca_key1='$ca_key3') OR (ca_key2!='' AND ca_key2='$ca_key3') OR (ca_key3!='' AND ca_key3='$ca_key3'))");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($selectKeys) === 0){
            if ($result = $con->query("INSERT INTO ws_campaigns (ca_id, ca_name, ca_content, ca_fk_us_id, ca_img, ca_prefix,ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3) VALUES ('','$ca_title', '$ca_content','$id','$ca_img','$ca_prefix','$ca_key1','$ca_key2','$ca_key3')")) {
             echo $con->insert_id;
          }
        }

        else{
            echo "No se ha creado la campaña. <br>Alguna de las palabras clave utilizadas ya están presentes en una campaña anterior.";
        }


    }else{
        //DEVOLUCIÓN ID CAMPAÑA
        if ($result = $con->query("INSERT INTO ws_campaigns (ca_id, ca_name, ca_content, ca_fk_us_id, ca_img, ca_prefix,ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3) VALUES ('','$ca_title', '$ca_content','$id','$ca_img','$ca_prefix','$ca_key1','$ca_key2','$ca_key3')")) {
             echo $con->insert_id;
          }

    }
```